# HttpClient connecting to azure server on network restore throws an error - unable to connect to remote server

Tags: c#, azure, httpclient

Query is made from a httpclient hosted in WPF control to azure server and azure server sends the results back to WPF control. When the Internet connection is disabled and postasync query is made httprequestexception is thrown. When the internet connection is restored and postaysnc query is made , post async works fine and if i disable the internet connection again and make the post async throws the exception. Once the internet connection is reestablished the postasync throws the httprequest exception. How to resolve this issue.

```
var httpContent = new StringContent(value, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var queryUri = new Uri(httpClient.BaseAddress, "content/resultvalue");
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(queryUri, httpContent);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var resultJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(resultJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behavior. If it cannot connect to the server, an exception is thrown. This is described in the documentation for `HttpClient.PostAsync` under the [Exception Handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpclient.postasync#exception-handling) heading.

If you need to catch the exception, then put it in a `try`/`catch` block and do something with the exception.

```
var httpContent = new StringContent(value, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var queryUri = new Uri(httpClient.BaseAddress, "content/resultvalue");
try {
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(queryUri, httpContent);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var resultJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(resultJson);
} catch (Exception e) {
    //report the exception to the user
}
```

Comment: I added the try catch block , but when the internet connection is restored , if  a new query made, the exception occurs, what's the reason for this and how to resolve

Comment: i have also noticed on the internet connection restore the post async works sometimes.

Comment: It depends what the message in the exception says. It will tell you why it's failing.

Comment: I am getting the error - unable to connect to the remote server.

Comment: whats the reason for this and why this error occurs on internetconnection restore?

Comment: Maybe you didn't wait long enough after restoring the connection before you tested.

Comment: That indicates a problem with your network connection, not your code.

Comment: Okay. I waited for 5 minutes after the internet connection restored and then  i made query, strange thing is it postasync is successful sometime,sometimes it is failure.

Comment: I couldn't tell you why, except that it's not your code causing the problem.